# Argo CD CLI error when installing on Windows 10 via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, argocd

I'm trying to install ArgoCD CLI on my windows 10 PC by following the command from the website substituting the version but receive the below error. It does not seem to like the + operator? Can anybody assist?

**PS C:\Users\dell.docker> $url = "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/" + v2.2.3 + "/argocd-windows-amd64.exe"**

```
At line:1 char:66
+ ...  = "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/" + v2.2.3  ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator.
At line:1 char:67
+ ... ps://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/" + v2.2.3 + "/arg ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'v2.2.3' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must *quote* the version number:

```sh
$url = "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/" + 'v2.2.3' + "/argocd-windows-amd64.exe"
```

Of course, you can also use only *one* quoted string to begin with, which - due to use of an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) - would even work if the version number were provided via a *variable*:

```sh
$version = 'v2.2.3' # Quoting is required here too - '...' is a verbatim string
$url = "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/$version/argocd-windows-amd64.exe"
```

---

> It does not seem to like the + operator

It's not the `+` operator that's the problem, it's the use of what you intend to be a *string* literal - `v2.2.3` - *without quoting*.

Operators operate in the context of *expressions* in PowerShell (expression mode), and in expressions all string literals require quoting.

By contrast, only when you pass *arguments* to *commands* (argument mode) may you pass string values (without spaces and other metacharacters) without quoting:

```sh
Write-Output v2.2.3  # OK - quoting optional
```

See the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic for more information about these two fundamental parsing modes.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for the fast response. Adding the quotes around the version fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BigRed247; my pleasure.